# Como ajustar toda a tela de acordo com a resolução do monitor?

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap

Como ajustar toda a tela de acordo com a resolução do monitor?

Vejam a imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu dashboard esta ficando como na imagem **B** como eu poderia fazer para ficar como a **A**.

Estou usando php + mysql + bootstrap + html.

Segue código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/favicon.ico"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
        <title>PAINEL DE MONITORAMENTO</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/datatables.css">
        <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/datatables.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.size-x {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

.circle {
    background: #008000;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-size: 10em;

    display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;

    -webkit-align-items: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;

  justify-content: center;
}
</style>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<br />
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">PAINEL DE MONITORAMENTO - TI</a>
<br />  


<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><center>CHAMADOS FECHADOS HOJE:</center></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
     <center><div class='size-x circle' style="height: 300px;"><?php echo"$fechados";?></div></center>
    </div> 
    </div>  
  </div>
<div class="col-md-8">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><center>AGUARDANDO ATENDIMENTO</center></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
       <div id="abertos" style="width: 90%; height: 300px;"></div>
    </div> 
    </div>  
  </div>
  </div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><center>EM ATENDIMENTO</center></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <center>
          <div id="analitico" style="width: 90%; height: 300px;"></div>
    </center>
    </div>  
    </div>  
  </div> 

    <div class="col-md-6">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><center>EM ATRASO</center></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <center>
       <div id="geral" style="width: 90%; height: 300px;"></div>
    </center>
     </div>   
 </div> 
     </div>   

  </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','bar']});

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(abertos);
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(analitico);
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(geral);



      function abertos() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Effort', 'Amount given'],
          ['EM ABERTOS',              <?php echo"$abertos"; ?>],
          ['AGUARDANDO ATENDIMENTO',  <?php echo"$aguardandoat"; ?>],
        ]);

        var options = {
          pieHole: 0.5,
          pieSliceText : 'value',
          pieSliceTextStyle: {
            color: 'black',
          },
          colors: ['#1E90FF', '#FFA500', '#FFA500', '#FF0000','#FF0000'],
        is3D:true
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('abertos'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }



    function analitico() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["PERIODO", "VALOR", { role: "style" } ],
        ["1 DIA",          8.94, "#008000"],
        ["3 DIAS",        10.49, "#FFFF00"],
        ["5 DIAS",        19.30, "#FF0000"]
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);

      var options = {
        title: "CHAMADOS EM ATENDIMENTO A:",
        is3D:true,
        bar: {groupWidth: "80%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("analitico"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }


    function geral() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["PERIODO", "VALOR", { role: "style" } ],
        ["1 DIA",                    8.94, "#008000"],
        ["5 DIAS",                  10.49, "#7FFF00"],
        ["7 DIA",                    8.94, "#FFFF00"],
        ["30 DIAS",                 10.49, "#FF8C00"],
        ["ACIMA DE 30 DIAS",        19.30, "#FF0000"]
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);

      var options = {
        title: "CHAMADOS EM ATENDIMENTO A:",
        bar: {groupWidth: "80%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
        is3D:true,
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("geral"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pode adicionar o código na pergunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparando as imagens só falta definir o height da row principal em cada tabela da imagem B

```
 row {
      height: numero+vw;
 }
```

"vw" é uma propriedade relativa do CSS que se adéqua com o height portanto o layout irá acompanhar o resize do navegador

Comment: Com base no meu código acima poderia me dar um exemplo ?, pois não entendi bem

Comment: aplique ao container 'container-fluid' um widht:100%; e as rows filhas um height 50vw;

Comment: Consegui,Obrigado.